# how to throw when user click on save button without entering the input value. How I can achieve it only in html or angularjs

Tags: input, field

how to throw when user click on save button without entering the input value. How I can achieve it only in html or angular

how to throw when user click on save button without entering the input value. How I can achieve it only in html or angular

Comment: What do you mean by "throw"? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to show an error when user clicks on save button if input field is empty.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. You forgot to share all attempts